# how to save all __init__() method and how to get the data in python

Tags: python

```
class BotoS3:

    def __init__(self):
        self.region = os.getenv('AWS_REGION')
        self.bucket = os.getenv('AWS_S3_BUCKET_SITE_CONFIG')
        self.aws_key = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        self.aws_secret = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

These keys having data.

How to save these variables and how to fetch the information in python?

Comment: What do you mean, "save"?

Comment: you can access this everywhere in your code `os.getenv('AWS_REGION')`

Comment: I think he means to write a file and read from it when he execute the code another time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create env variables.
There are several options here:

1. First of all you can create config file and save that variables in it. When you start your script/application you will load config (using `import` for example). You can use more improvement tools : [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).
2. You can serialize it to, for example, pickle.

Code example:

```
import pickle

class BotoS3:

    def __init__(self):
        self.region = os.getenv('AWS_REGION')
        self.bucket = os.getenv('AWS_S3_BUCKET_SITE_CONFIG')
        self.aws_key = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        self.aws_secret = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

with open('botos.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    botos1 = BotoS3(...) # create object here
    pickle.dump(botos1, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
del botos1

with open('botos.pkl', 'rb') as input:
    botos1 = pickle.load(input)
```

Comment: I asssume ```company1``` is supposed to be ```botos1```?